# Example of rational projective variety of Picard number 1

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there any example (or more ambitiously, classification) of $X$ with following properties?

- $X$ is a variety over $\mathbb{C}$;
- $X$ is projective and normal;
- $\rho(X) = 1$;
- $X$ is birational to $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Also, I want to hear a result after adding a singularity condition: 
How about when $X$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial?
How about $X$ is non-singular?

I can't find an example which is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^n$.
The only result I know in this direction is Mori's theorem:
If a nonsingular variety $X$ has ample tangent bundle, then $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: There a plenty of nonsingular examples: quadrics, Grassmanians...

Comment: There are also non-homogeneous examples, e.g., an intersection of two generic quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^5$, certain cubic hypersurfaces in $\mathh{P}^{2n+1}$ with $n>1$, moduli spaces of rank $r$ vector bundles on a fixed genus $g>1$ curve with fixed determinant of degree $d$ relatively prime to $r$, ...  

Comment: Oh, I thought it too difficult way... Thank you for comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hyperquadrics of dimension at least three.